# sql server: finding names with repetitive char

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I want to find names with repetitive char in them for example :

- ana
- asdbbiop
- a1for1
- @mail@ban

I found a similar question here but they were consecutive ones.

I know 2 way :

1.using helping table and join

2.a very long "where  like"  statement

is there any way to do it with regex?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It's name is CLR. You can write your assembly or google up some solution already written

Comment: SQL Server does not have native support for regular expressions, so there is no way to do this with a regex, unless you add those functions into the database.

Comment: I would connect to the DB with Python, select the data and do my string comparisons from there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This codes will helps you find the repetitive characters find in the word and count of characters

### Sample Data

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT,String nvarchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT 1,'ana'          UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'asdbbiop'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'a1for1'       UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'@mail@ban'

    SELECT  * FROM @Table
```

Using Recursive Cte we get the expected Result

```
;With cte
AS
(
SELECT ID, String
        ,CAST(LEFT(String,1)AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Letter
        ,RIGHT(String,LEN(String)-1)  AS Remainder 
FROM @Table
WHERE LEN(String)>1

UNION ALL
SELECT ID, String
        ,CAST(LEFT(Remainder,1)AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Letter
        ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-1)  AS Remainder 
FROM cte
WHERE LEn(Remainder)>0
)
SELECT ID,
       String, 
       letter, 
       Ascii(letter) AS CharCode, 
       Count(letter) AS CountOfLetter 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY ID,
          String, 
          letter, 
          Ascii(letter) 
HAVING COUNT(letter)>1
```

Result

```
ID  String  letter  CharCode    CountOfLetter
---------------------------------------------
1   ana         a     97          2
2   asdbbiop    b     98          2
3   a1for1      1     49          2
4   @mail@ban   @     64          2
4   @mail@ban   a     97          2
```